# Converting std::string to Lowercase Inside Function

Tags: c++

I was in need of a fast portable function, that could convert a string to it's lower case. After researching I came up with this code, that sadly doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
void low_string(string);
int main()
{
            string lower = "This is MIX case TEST";
            low_string(lower);
            cout << lower;
            return 0;
}
void low_string(string lower)
{
    transform(lower.begin(), lower.end(), lower.begin(), ::tolower);
}
```

The string still remains uppercase. I think it has to do something with reference passing etc, but being new to the language I cannot figure out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to recieve the string by reference and not value. std::string& lower

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You forgot to pass by reference.  `void low_string(string lower)` => `void low_string(string& lower)`

Comment: @NathanOliver  wow! and I was looking places for the error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the string by value, so the parameter `lower` in your function is actually a copy of the argument `lower` in `main`.

change your code to `void low_string(string& lower)` and it should work

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the copy of the string, not the string itself.
You should consider passing by reference instead:

```
void low_string(string & lower)
{
    transform(lower.begin(), lower.end(), lower.begin(), ::tolower);
}
```